# fine-uploader generate more unique custom file ids

Tags: fine-uploader

I am trying to change the default file ids (e.g. 0,1,2,..) to something more unique, but I haven't succeeded. Due to UI purposes, I need to create files list not like:

`qq-file-id-1`

but like:

`qq-file-id-ahGklm`

is there any way to achieve this?

Thank you

---

My UI has 2 parts:
1) A modal window where the user adds files and using thumbnails is able to see all his files before uploading. There is the "upload" button.
2) A second container (outside the modal) where the user sees the uploading progress of each file.

This scenario works perfect! Before uploading I am getting the html (using jquery) from the modal and put it into the second container.
The problem appears while uploading, when the user selects again new files. Due to the Fine Uploader's functionality, when I update (with the new files) the second container, the UI progress status conflicts due to duplicates file ids. I tried to modify the code but it was too complicated for me.

---

Thank you Mark for your response!
Currently, the modal contains the template (files list & button) that helps the users to add and remove files. Bellow this area I am placing a "upload" button. When the user clicks on this button, I "cut-paste" (using jquery) the specific area into another div outside the modal. Everything works fine, until the user adds new files to modal. If the uploading queue (placed on a different div from modal) contains e.g. 3 files and the user adds from modal even 1 file, the progress of the new file (qq-file-id-1) conflicts with the progress of the first queued file.

Comment: Not sure this is a great idea. These elements (along with their id's: `qq-file-id-1`) are used internally by Fine Uploader to do some UI things in UI mode. All my ideas involve overriding this via external JS, but I'm looking into how that may affect Fine Uploader's operation. Mind outlining your use case? Maybe this could be a feature if it's worthy.

Answer (score 0):

The numerical ids you are seeing (0, 1, 2, ...) are the indexes of the files in Fine Uploader's internal file list (an Array). Every time a file is added, obviously, this number is incremented.

There is not a function you could override to change this. In fact, you'd have to rewrite a considerable portion of Fine Uploader's internal code. Either way, these aren't numbers that you should be relying on to retrieve your file. You should be relying on the callbacks and the `getFile` method to retrieve your file(s) at certain times.

What you could do is change your [template](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/styling.html) so the file list and upload buttons are part of the modal window that was originally hidden. When the user triggers the modal window it appears and the user can add and remove files at will. When the window closes, the user can press the upload button (still part of Fine Uploader's template, but not hidden) to start the upload. Note that [autoUpload](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html) would have to be false and you would have to [add an event handler to the upload button](http://fineuploader.com/fine-uploader-with-jquery-wrapper-demo.html#demo1).